# How to encode and decode string and emoji

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to send the emoji and string to the server in react native. How to use the encode the emoji and string and decode the emoji and string method in react native

Comment: Emoji are part of the string.

Comment: research "unicode emoji"

Comment: You can read this [article](https://medium.com/reactnative/emojis-in-javascript-f693d0eb79fb)